# How to change gcc to tcc when compiling using makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

What do I need to change in this Makefile

```
.POSIX:
.SUFFIXES:

include config.mk

# flags for compiling
DWLCPPFLAGS = -I. -DWLR_USE_UNSTABLE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" $(XWAYLAND)
DWLDEVCFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -Wunused-macros\
    -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=implicit -Werror=return-type -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types

# CFLAGS / LDFLAGS
PKGS      = wlroots wayland-server xkbcommon libinput $(XLIBS)
DWLCFLAGS = `$(PKG_CONFIG) --cflags $(PKGS)` $(DWLCPPFLAGS) $(DWLDEVCFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
LDLIBS    = `$(PKG_CONFIG) --libs $(PKGS)` $(LIBS)

all: dwl
dwl: dwl.o util.o
    $(CC) dwl.o util.o $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) $(DWLCFLAGS) -o $@
dwl.o: dwl.c config.mk config.h client.h xdg-shell-protocol.h wlr-layer-shell-unstable-v1-protocol.h
util.o: util.c util.h

# wayland-scanner is a tool which generates C headers and rigging for Wayland
# protocols, which are specified in XML. wlroots requires you to rig these up
# to your build system yourself and provide them in the include path.
WAYLAND_SCANNER   = `$(PKG_CONFIG) --variable=wayland_scanner wayland-scanner`
WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS = `$(PKG_CONFIG) --variable=pkgdatadir wayland-protocols`

xdg-shell-protocol.h:
    $(WAYLAND_SCANNER) server-header \
        $(WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS)/stable/xdg-shell/xdg-shell.xml $@
wlr-layer-shell-unstable-v1-protocol.h:
    $(WAYLAND_SCANNER) server-header \
        protocols/wlr-layer-shell-unstable-v1.xml $@

config.h:
    cp config.def.h $@
clean:
    rm -f dwl *.o *-protocol.h

dist: clean
    mkdir -p dwl-$(VERSION)
    cp -R LICENSE* Makefile README.md client.h config.def.h\
        config.mk protocols dwl.1 dwl.c util.c util.h dwl.desktop\
        dwl-$(VERSION)
    tar -caf dwl-$(VERSION).tar.gz dwl-$(VERSION)
    rm -rf dwl-$(VERSION)

install: dwl
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
    cp -f dwl $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
    chmod 755 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/dwl
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1
    cp -f dwl.1 $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1
    chmod 644 $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1/dwl.1
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(DATADIR)/wayland-sessions
    cp -f dwl.desktop $(DESTDIR)$(DATADIR)/wayland-sessions/dwl.desktop
    chmod 644 $(DESTDIR)$(DATADIR)/wayland-sessions/dwl.desktop
uninstall:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/dwl $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1/dwl.1 $(DESTDIR)$(DATADIR)/wayland-sessions/dwl.desktop

.SUFFIXES: .c .o
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DWLCFLAGS) -c $<
```

I tried to replace CC with tcc, change gcc in c99 to tcc.All dependencies are installed and work well when compiled with gcc.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of such "changes", nor any idea what "I couldn't get any results" means.

Comment: Add `CC = tcc` to your makefile to use `tcc` as the compiler.  Add `CC = c99` to use `c99`.  Do not replace the `$(CC)` with `tcc`.  Be **sure** to delete all the objects from the previous build, before you start a new build with a different compiler.  If this doesn't work you need to be more clear about exactly what changes you made, what you see when you run make, and what the errors are (cut and paste with code block formatting).